# impala error ,sometimes it runs and sometimes not

Tags: sql, hadoop2, impala

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT int_col
  FROM functional.alltypes) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN functional.alltypes t2 ON (t2.bigint_col=5)

**ERROR:** NotImplementedException: Error generating a valid execution plan for this query. A RIGHT OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan.

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) The error is suspicious, because the join is a `left join`, not a `right join`.  (3) Nevertheless, the error seems pretty clear.

Comment: Hi Gordon,I edited my question .  It is strange because there is no right join in the query SQL text.